# Why does this parallelized Mersenne prime calculation algorithm hang?

Tags: java, java-stream, biginteger

Trying out the code from [this video of Joshua Bloch](https://youtu.be/hSfylUXhpkA?t=1777), I've added `.parallel()` to the original code trying to make it a bit faster (in terms of speed of execution). As a result, it began to hang, it didn't complete after 5 minutes of running, while its sequential version completes in seconds.

*I wonder, what can be the reason for the following code to hang after it was parallelized?*

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.math.BigInteger.ONE;
import static java.math.BigInteger.TWO;

class Scratch {

    static Stream<BigInteger> primes() {
        return Stream.iterate(TWO, BigInteger::nextProbablePrime);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        primes().map(p -> TWO.pow(p.intValueExact()).subtract(ONE))
            .filter(mersenne -> mersenne.isProbablePrime(50))
            .limit(20)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

P.S.

The `parallelism` of the underlying `ForkJoinPool` is 12.

Comment: Did you read the book, it has all the necessary explanations.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Which book? I think deleting your answer because it exist in the book is a wrong idea

Comment: @RavindraRanwala: He edited his question to make clear he watched a video rather than read from a book.

Comment: See the [API Notes for limit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-).

Comment: @James Reinstate Monica Polk `filter()` is needed because only Mersenne prime numbers should be generated (the `map()` step generates the candidates for Mersenne prime numbers).

Comment: @StefanZobel: Of course, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**

This is **not** an answer, but posting all of that in a comment is not possible and would be hard to read.

---

Finding each [Mersenne prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) takes longer time than the previous one as can be seen by removing `.parallel()` and changing `.limit(20)` to a higher value.

**Observation 1**

One would think that using parallelism on this stream ignores the `.limit(20)` directive, but that is not the case as if we change the limit to a lower value - for example to `.limit(10)`, we'll get exactly the first 10 mersenne primes (unordered, but that's expected):

```
primes().map(p -> TWO.pow(p.intValueExact()).subtract(ONE))
        .filter(mersenne -> mersenne.isProbablePrime(50))
        .limit(10)
        .parallel()
        .forEach(m -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + m));
```

Sample output:

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3: 8191
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-13: 131071
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19: 524287
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-23: 2305843009213693951
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5: 31
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9: 7
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-31: 2147483647
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-27: 3
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-17: 127
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7: 618970019642690137449562111
```

(note that all use a worker on `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` - there's [workaround](https://medium.com/@michaelbespalov/parallel-stream-pitfalls-and-how-to-avoid-them-91f11808a16c) for that, but this is irrelevant to the problem)

**Observation 2**

If we limit the input stream get by `primes()` - for example to `700`, the program completes as expected:

```
primes().limit(700)
        .map(p -> TWO.pow(p.intValueExact()).subtract(ONE))
        .filter(mersenne -> mersenne.isProbablePrime(50))
        .limit(20)
        .parallel()
        .forEach(m -> System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + m));
```

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19: 6...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3: 21...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19: 2...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-23: 1...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5: 68...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-23: 7...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19: 1...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-13: 4...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3: 81...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-17: 5...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7: 25...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3: 12...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-13: 1...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-19: 3...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-23: 3...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-31: 1...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5: 52...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9: 28...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-27: 1...
ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-21: 1...
```

Changing input stream limit to a higher value (1000, 1500 etc.) increases the time required for the program to complete while the final result remains correct (20 mersenne primes).

---

Taking into account both observations above, an *educated guess* would be that when this stream is `.parallel()`, more input elements than required to get the desired result are processed.

When required `mersenne primes` count is high (above ~14) and input stream has no limit (as it is in the example), the program could take very long time to complete and is effectively hung.

Comment: It's close enough to answer to be given as an answer. It all seems a bit magical and mysterious as to when upstream results are sent downstream and how something downstream like`limit()` tells upstream producers to stop.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, the program doesn't hang but stumbles upon checking some big numbers for primariness.

When there is no limit at the initial source (kudos to @MartinBG for the clue), the underlying `Spliterator` advances too much (considering the task) and gives bigger numbers as a source for the downstream, resulting in extreme computational complexity.

I've modified the input, so it doesn't advance that much and returns only the next probable prime as the next chunk of `Spliterator`. I.e., every time a thread from the pool is ready to proceed with the following number it has to receive a new chunk that consist of a single number, contrary to the big pieces that typically observed.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

import static java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE;
import static java.math.BigInteger.ONE;
import static java.math.BigInteger.TWO;

class Scratch {

    static Stream<BigInteger> primes() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterator<>() {

            private AtomicReference<BigInteger> seedReference = new AtomicReference<>(TWO);

            private BigInteger resolveNextProbablePrime() {
                return seedReference.getAndUpdate(BigInteger::nextProbablePrime);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super BigInteger> action) {
                action.accept(resolveNextProbablePrime());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Spliterator<BigInteger> trySplit() {
                return Spliterators.spliterator(new BigInteger[]{resolveNextProbablePrime()}, characteristics());
            }

            @Override
            public long estimateSize() {
                return MAX_VALUE;
            }

            @Override
            public int characteristics() {
                return ORDERED & DISTINCT & SORTED & NONNULL & IMMUTABLE & CONCURRENT;
            }
        }, true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        primes().map(p -> TWO.pow(p.intValueExact()).subtract(ONE))
            .filter(mersenne -> mersenne.isProbablePrime(50))
            .limit(20)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The new version of the program completes in seconds, utilizing multiple cores for its computations.

The given solution is still not a cure for the encountered trait; it just works in this particular case, since it's rather safe to take a couple of next probable primes and perform calculations from them.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your hardware, it's still possible to get 20 numbers. The problem here is the parallel stream may not give you too much performance gain. Remove `parallel` call:

```
primes().map(p -> TWO.pow(p.intValueExact()).subtract(ONE))
        .filter(mersenne -> mersenne.isProbablePrime(50))
        .limit(20) 
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It can be finished in about 50 seconds on my machine (i5-6300u, 2.4GHz). 
Or:

```
primes().map(p -> TWO.pow(p.intValueExact()).subtract(ONE))
        .filter(mersenne -> mersenne.isProbablePrime(50))
        .limit(20)
        .parallel()
        .sorted()
        .sequential()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```